# Freeze User through code and make report on them

Tags: user

As you know, there is freeze user feature came up in latest release. We can freeze the user if we are not ready to deactivate it .

how can i freeze a User with code ?
Can we report on the Freeze users ?

I could not find any field on user which shows whether a user is frozen or not .

Comment: What would be the use case for this functionality? Presumably, you're freezing a user because you intend to permanently deactivate them.

Comment: A user can be linked to other multiple records. To deactivate it we have to remove all the links whereas if a freezed user can be linked to other records. the functionality gives time to Admin to do all the impact analysis before deactivating the user.

Comment: I know what freezing is. I meant, what would be the point of freezing a user through code instead of manually?

Comment: Yeah. I do know not the explanation here.But, this is the requirement. Could u pls me with How to make a report on the freeze user. Admin wants a report on who all are freeze user.

Comment: As far as I can tell, what you're asking for is impossible. No documentation states that you can report or query frozen users, or toggle this flag through any API or Apex Code. The point of asking "why" is so that salesforce.com might run across this question, and want to know what business use case it might possibly have. Without any reason why, other than "because we want to", salesforce.com is likely not to deliver such a feature until they feel they have time, which might be never. You should find out why they want this.

Comment: Personally, I can't see any justification for "why" you would want a report on frozen users. After all, freezing is supposed to be temporary, long enough to change settings to disable them permanently. Furthermore, since this is a UI intensive process, I see no reason to allow this happen to be programmed through the API, either. I feel that salesforce.com likely has these same sentiments, and I would not have expected them to provide API access to freezing, because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Based on the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm), the User IsActive field "Indicates whether the user has access to log in (true) or not (false)". However, I suspect this doesn't take into account the v29.0 freeze user functionality.

Comment: thanks sfdcfox. I understand your explanation and logic behind it .

Answer (score 8):

the [UserLogin](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userlogin.htm) SObject has an `IsFrozen` field, you can set this to true (from apex, api etc) to freeze a user. You can query this field from SOQL to determine who is frozen (and also who has a password lockout in effect), I haven't looked but i'd think you can do a regular report against this object as well.

Comment: That link is taking me to the base SOAP API page, so I went and found a different link for anyone who needs it: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userlogin.htm

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't able to find a way to do this from regular Apex, but it is possible using the SOAP API.  I've blogged a Visualforce solution that uses the Ajax toolkit to retrieve the frozen status of the users and provide buttons to freeze/unfreeze each user:

http://bobbuzz.me.uk/185q7Yg

Answer (score 5):

Here is some sample code that I used to this:

```
List<UserLogin> users = [SELECT IsFrozen,UserId FROM UserLogin WHERE UserId IN 
    (SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name != 'System Administrator' 
    AND UserType = 'Standard' AND IsActive=True) 
    AND UserId != :UserInfo.getUserId()];
for (UserLogin ul : users) { ul.isFrozen = True; }
update(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in two ways:
1) Using Dataloader
2) Scripts to execute in Developer console
http://theblogreaders.com/users-freeze-unfreeze-salesforce-using-script/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a few clicks with sfdx-hardis VsCode extension :)

[image]

You can see details in the following article

https://medium.com/@dimitrimonge/freeze-unfreeze-users-during-salesforce-deployment-8a1488bf8dd3

*Disclaimer: I work in the company providing this open-source plugin*

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to accomplish this.

Created two fields on USER:

| Type | Field Name |
| --- | --- |
| Checkbox | Freeze_User__c |
| Datetime | Freeze_User_DateTime__c |

I created a workflow rule to check the Freeze User field at specific datetime

```
User: Freeze User DateTimeNOT EQUAL TOnull
TimeBased Action:  0 Hours after Freeze User TimeDate -> Check Freeze_User__c
```

Then I created the following Methods:

```
public static void FreezeUser(List <User> listUsers, Map <ID, User> oldUserMap) {
    list <UserLogin> listUpdatetoFrozen = new list <UserLogin>();
    list <User> listFrozenUsers = new list<user>();
    set <string> setFrozenUserIds = new set <string>();
    
    for(User u : listUsers)
    {
        if(u.Freeze_User__c != oldUserMap.get(u.Id).Freeze_user__c) //if frozen has changed
        {                            
            if(u.Freeze_User__c = True)
            {
                listFrozenUsers.add(u);
                setFrozenUserIds.add(u.id);
            }
        }

        if(!setFrozenuserIds.isempty())
        {
            list <UserLogin> FrozenUsers = [SELECT ID, isFrozen FROM UserLogin WHERE UserID IN :setFrozenUserIds];        
            
            for(UserLogin ulog : FrozenUsers)
            {
                string Id = ulog.Id;
                boolean FrozenStatus = True;
                listUpdatetoFrozen.add(UserUtility.FreezeUserUpdate(Id, FrozenStatus));
            }
            update listUpdatetoFrozen;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static UserLogin FreezeUserUpdate (string Id, Boolean FrozenStatus) {
    UserLogin ulog = new UserLogin();
    ulog.Id = Id;
    ulog.IsFrozen = FrozenStatus;
    return ulog;
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class UserHandlerTest {
    @IsTest
    public static void Method1() {
        list <User> listactiveUsers = [SELECT Id, Freeze_User__c FROM USER WHERE isActive = True AND Freeze_User__c = False LIMIT 200];
        list <User> listUpdateUser = new list <User>();

        for(User u : listActiveUsers)
        {
            u.Freeze_User__c = True;
            listUpdateUser.add(u);
        }
        update listUpdateUser;
    }
}
```